# variable classname in javascript in loop

Tags: javascript

in Javascript, I have a row of elements with identical div's:

```
(....loop, where "count" is a number that can distinguish the columns in the row)
<other divs>
  <div class="pie"></div>
</div>
```

and then I am doing something like this:

```
 <% var strng = 'rotate 40deg' %>
 <% $("other divs... .pie").css({'-webkit-transform': strng}); %>
```

so that I can rotate each individual element. The problem is, since my Javascript selector just does "pie", all the individual column elements get rotated the same amount.

It seems that I want something like this:

```
<other divs>
  <div class"pie">
    <div class=count></div>
  </div>
```

and then the selector would be something like this:

```
<% $("other divs... .pie" + " ." + count).css({'-webkit-transform': strng}); %>
```

but this doesn't seem to work. How can I use a variable class name?

EDIT: count is just a number. I will add a string in front of the number and see if that works - thanks for noting that a class name can't start with a number.

EDIT: I'd like to understand why I am losing points for this question. It's a serious question and I need to figure it out. I closed it, even though I didn't get an answer that works yet. I suppose the question just looked stupid to people?

EDIT: there is now a JSFiddle. I need to get it working initially - and then I will add the things I am trying to work out.

http://jsfiddle.net/VJHcH/12/

Comment: A class name is just a string, how its created doesn't matter AFAIK. I suspect it's something else. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: What is `count`? What does the actual markup look like?

Comment: Do the class names consist of a number only?

Comment: Give us more details like sample html, code for rotation etc.. Or may be a fiddle as @Mathletics suggested

Comment: Class names **can** start with numbers in all modern browsers.  The specs being quoted are out of date.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks. I'm experimenting with it now.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure I understand where the downvotes come from either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A classname isn't allowed to start with a number. It has to have the following form (regex): `-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*`.

So it starts either with a `-` (dash), `_` (underscore), or a letter.

Instead of just using the `count` as the classname, use something like `".pie" + count`.

Edit: Apperently, since HTML 5, they are allowed to start with digits, but jQuery doesn't seem to select them correctly.

Comment: @Pointy - That link you pointed to says "Classnames can contain any character". This is clearly wrong--they can't contain a space character, for instance, without breaking a **lot** of things. The [official CSS3 syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#syntax) and the more lenient [CSS3 selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#w3cselgrammar) don't seem to allow for a class name to start with a number (or are entirely a number, as in OP's code). I suppose that there could be a spec somewhere that contradicts this; do you know of one?

Comment: @TedHopp yes that blog post doesn't make it very clear that whitespace is excluded from the "any character" thing :-) I believe that the key is the fact that identifiers in CSS *can* include escaped characters.

Comment: @Pointy - Escaped characters in class names were allowed in CSS2; that's nothing new. (I don't think it's new for identifiers, either, but I didn't look at that.) I don't know of any spec that allows a string of (unescaped) digits as a class name.

Comment: @TedHopp The [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html) does not allow the class to consisted of *unescaped* digits, but it can be *escaped* digits. Note that that's the **CSS** grammar, not the HTML grammar; HTML does not care at all about the characters in your class names.

Comment: @Pointy - Right--according to the grammar, class names cannot start with digits. So I'm trying to understand your comment "That is not true anymore". :)

Comment: @TedHopp ok fair enough, that may not have been the best way to say it. The point is that **in HTML** there's no need to worry about what characters can be in a class name (other than HTML special characters of course!) and in CSS selectors there are ways to deal with class names containing any non-whitespace character.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VJHcH/10/@Pointy, I created a JSFiddle, which I am trying to get started on. I can't get the Javascript to work to even get started. It is http://jsfiddle.net/VJHcH/10/

Comment: @Pointy, let me try to send this link again, for the JSFiddle. I'd like to get it running properly first... and then add the things I need.     http://jsfiddle.net/VJHcH/12/

Comment: @TedHopp, I'd like your help on this question if you have a moment. I started a JSFiddle, but it isn't working yet.    http://jsfiddle.net/VJHcH/12/

Comment: @sploiber your fiddle works fine if you select jQuery from the library chooser on the left side of the page.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks very much! You can see I am still getting used to this. OK, I will add the new stuff, to show what is not working. Then we can try to work out what is wrong.

Comment: @Pointy, it is updated now, with what I have not yet been able to work out. Somehow, the class selecting isn't right.

Comment: @sploiber it's not clear what exactly the problem is. What doesn't it do that you expect it to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22480/discussion-between-sploiber-and-pointy)